# Why file read/write adds additional lines to the file?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, line-breaks

I would like to unescape unicode characters in the source file:

```
source = open('source.csv', 'r')
target = open('target.csv', 'w')
target.write(source.read().decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-8'))
```

But the result file contains extra line breaks. For example, the text

```
u'\u0417a\u0439\u043c\u044b \u0412ce\u043c \u0436e\u043ba\u044e\u0449\u0438\u043c!\nO\u0434o\u0431\u0440e\u043d\u0438e 98%'
```

is replaced with

```
u'Зaймы Вceм жeлaющим!
Oдoбрeниe 98%'
```

Understand that there is line break symbol `\n` in the source text, but I would like to keep it as is without actual conversion to line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
for line in source:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    line = line.decode('unicode_escape').replace(u'\n', u'\\n').encode('utf8')
    target.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks. But now each and every line starts with `\n` what I don't have in the source file. And again some extra lines were added (trying to find problematic lines).

Comment: @LA_: Fixed, see answer.

Comment: The file contains also `\r\n` and just `\r` symbols. I've tried to replace them with `\\n` and then with `\\r\\n` and `\\r` accordingly, but it either adds `\n` symbols at the end of each line and returns just one lines (i.e. misses all line breaks).

Comment: It might be easier to do the replace before the decode.

Comment: The following works well - `line.replace(u'\r\n', u'\\r\\n').replace(u'\r', u'\\r').replace(u'\n', u'\\n').rstrip('\\r')`. Thanks for your help.